# Mysql Where ... In ... AND where ... in ... should only match on same index

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE (`firstname` LIKE 'Luke' AND `lastname` LIKE 'Skywalker') OR  
 (`firstname` LIKE 'Foo' AND `lastname` LIKE 'Bar') OR 
(`firstname` LIKE 'Tom' AND `lastname` LIKE 'Turner');
```

But i would like to make it a bit more readable by using a where ... in ...
I tried

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE `firstname` 
    IN ('Luke','Foo','Tom') AND `lastname` IN ('Skywalker','Bar','Turner');
```

But unfortunately this will also match `"Tom Skywalker"`, `"Foo Turner"` and all mixes you can think off.

I have to select on first and lastname (perhaps more fields like DOB) since i am getting data from an external API and i have to check if those names are in our system.

Comment: What is the scale of data in your `users` table, and the number of rows from the external API that you will have to compare?  100's of rows?  50,000 rows?

Comment: I can get up to 1000 names back from the external API (I want to match facebook friends with users from my own database) my own database can get up to 10000 rows (it is currently in a testing fase, but i want to optimize all my sql query's at an early stage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE (firstname, lastname) 
      IN ( ('Luke', 'Skywalker') 
         , ('Foo' , 'Bar') 
         , ('Tom' , 'Turner')
         )
;
```

Comment: @safarov: Valid in MySQL, Postgres and Oracle 11g. Not in Sql-Server.

Answer (score 4):

Using `LIKE` operator without wildcards doesn't make much sense. I think you should use `=`, particularly if you have to `check if those names are in our system`.

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE (firstname = 'Luke' AND lastname = 'Skywalker') OR 
      (firstname = 'Foo' AND lastname = 'Bar') OR 
      (firstname = 'Tom' AND lastname = 'Turner')
```

If you use an `IN` operator, as you said, will match different combinations. I think the previous example should be the fastest way to compare them.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine them with `concat`:

```
WHERE concat(`firstname`,'-',`lastname`)
   IN ('Luke-Skywalker', 'Foo-Bar', 'Tom-Turner');
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it'll be quite slow

Comment: Good point.  I have added a clarification comment to the question.  If the dataset is small, I would prefer readability to performance.