# MySQL WHERE IN() AND IN()

Tags: php, mysql

I need to do something like:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid
FROM node node
LEFT JOIN term_node term_node ON node.vid = term_node.vid
LEFT JOIN node node_term_node ON term_node.vid = node_term_node.vid
WHERE
(node.type in ('casetracker_basic_project'))
AND
(term_node.tid IN (29, 44, etc.))
AND
(term_node.tid IN (124, 129, etc.))
```

But the second "AND" is inoperative.

I already saw this post: [Mysql Where ... In ... AND where ... in ... should only match on same index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111153/mysql-where-in-and-where-in-should-only-match-on-same-index) but I have way more possible combinations.

Comment: This question isn't too clear. Could you please post the tables' structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample?

Comment: `(term_node.tid IN (29, 44, etc.))
AND
(term_node.tid IN (124, 129, etc.))` is pretty meaningless... `term_node.tid` can only have one value at a time

Answer (score 0):

You need OR instead of second AND:

```
WHERE
node.type in ('casetracker_basic_project')
AND
(
term_node.tid IN (29, 44, etc.) OR term_node.tid IN (124, 129, etc.)
)
```

or collapse it (but probably you know better why you need this structure (maybe dynamically created)).

Answer (score 0):

```
AND (term_node.tid IN (29, 44, etc.))
AND (term_node.tid IN (124, 129, etc.))
```

could be collapsed in

```
AND (term_node.tid IN (29, 44, 124, 129, etc.))
```

and this will solve your problem